# Insert query in foreach not inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
    $ManagerName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ManagerName']);
    $Password = encryptIt($_POST['Password']);
    $Address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Address']);
    $Email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
    $PhoneNo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PhoneNo']);
    $OfficeName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['OfficeName']);

    $ConsignmentNo = $_POST['percel'];
    $status = 'In Transit';

    $det = explode(",",$ConsignmentNo);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_courier_officers (officer_name, off_pwd, address, email, ph_no, office, consignment, status, reg_date)
        VALUES ('$ManagerName', '$Password', '$Address', '$Email', '$PhoneNo', '$OfficeName','$ConsignmentNo','$status', NOW())";   

    $done = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    if($done){

    echo "added";

    foreach($det as $valuez)
    {
    $m = $Email;
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO courier_track (email, percel_num) values('$m', '$valuez')");

    }

    mysqli_query($mysqli, "insert into user_log (username,name,action,time, user_id, mydate, mtime)values('$uname','$fullname','Added $ManagerName to courier officers table', '$tv', '$id', '$t', '$tv')");

    }else{
        echo 'Error occured: '.$mysqli->error;
    }
```

After the first insertion is true, I want to submit the second query which is a **foreach loop**. I want it to submit the number of time the values occurs but it is not submitting after the first insertion.

All queries are working except for the query in the **foreach**.

Can someone please tell me what to do?

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns false on failure. Check for that. If it is false, check `mysqli_error` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Error will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: try displaying the query inside foreach and manually running it on your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this piece of code

```
 mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO courier_track (email, percel_num) values('$m', '$valuez')");
```

with an error notification as follows

```
 mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO courier_track (email, percel_num) values('$m', '$valuez')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

then you will get to know what is wrong in the insert statement.

If it doesn't work put a print_r($det); and add it to the OP so that we can figure out the problem rightly

Comment: Thanks. it says the table id doesn't have a default value; forgotten it has no auto increment. Inserting now.